# Cancelable Component @Ouput EventEmitter?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, rxjs

If I have a custom Angular Component, let's say, `MyPanelComponent`/`<my-panel>` how could I implement functionality where if something calls `MyPanelComponent.closePanel()` I could allow something else the chance to stop the panel from closing?

What I have in mind is something like this:

**home.component.html:**

```
<my-panel (closing)="panelIsClosing($event)"> ... </my-panel>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
panelIsClosing(event: any) {
  if (!allowPanelClose) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

So the expected behavior would be:

1. Something calls `closePanel()` on the `<my-panel>` instance.
2. `HomeComponent` is notified that the panel is trying to close and can optionally cancel the panel from closing.
3. If nothing cancels it, the `<my-panel>` instance will proceed to close.

I'm not sure where to start with this, but I think being able to use RxJS `Observable`s would be ideal.

EDIT: I know the [DevExtreme](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular) library does something like this, I think I found [how they implement it](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/blob/master/src/core/events-strategy.ts) but I haven't managed to wrap my head around it just yet, and it's probably more than I need...

Comment: You could define your own function to handle the close-cancelling logic, and emit it through your @Output event

Comment: Check an alternative version of the accepted answer, using the native CustomEvent API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386214/3317037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PanelComponent, you could leverage the fact that the default behavior of `EventEmitter` is synchronous*

```
  close() {
    this.closing.emit({
      preventClose: () => {
        this.closePrevented = true
      }
    });

    if (this.closePrevented) {
      return;
    }

    // Go on with closing implementation
  }
```

A very bare-bones/basic demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-cancellable-event-emitter).

* Reference: [EventEmitter docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: This looks like the kind of solution I was looking for. Are there any downsides to exploiting the fact that `EventEmitter` is synchronous? I can immediately think of one: If the logic to decide whether to close or not needs to make an HTTP request before it can decide, it would be blocking execution, right?

Comment: I can't really think of any unless you're passing the same instance of your PanelComponent around, and have multiple listeners bound to the same Output and prevent closing differently (which would be a real mess and should be avoided).
It's not really exploiting - I believe it's intended to be this way. You could set your EventEmitter to be Async by passing `true` when constructing a new EventEmitter: `new EventEmitter(true)` if ever needed

Comment: hey, check this improved version, using the native CustomEvent API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386214/3317037

Answer (score 1):

Easiest option would be to for your panel component to separate the close in 2 different steps. The **close** event and a method that actually closes it.

It would look something like this:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-confirmable',
  templateUrl: './confirmable.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./confirmable.component.css']
})
export class ConfirmableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output()
  public close = new EventEmitter();

  @Input()
  public text: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public actualClose() {
    console.log('actual close logic');
  }
  public notifyClosure() {
    this.close.emit();
  }
}
```

```html
<button (click)="notifyClosure()">{{text}}</button>
```

Then where it used you can decide if you want to actually close it or not.

```html
<app-confirmable text="I will never go away" (close)="doNotClose()"></app-confirmable>

<app-confirmable #confirmable text="I will never go away"(close)="confirmable.actualClose()"></app-confirmable>
```

If you need the reference inside the controller you can obtain it with **@ViewChild**.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-optional-close)'s a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1):

Built upon the previous @outersky answer, Even better if you could leverage the already standard API of native CustomEvent and do something like this:

```
export class CancellableEvent<T> extends CustomEvent<T> {
  detail: T;

  constructor(detail: T) {
    super('cancellableEvent', {
      detail,
      cancelable: true
    });
  }
}

const event = new CancellableEvent({ some: 'property' });

event.defaultPrevented; // returns false
event.preventDefault();
event.defaultPrevented; // returns true
event.detail; // returns { some: 'property' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

Create a CancelableEvent interface, fire it and check whether it's canceled before doing something

```
export interface CancelableEvent<T> {
    data:T;
    canceled : boolean;
}

// fire event:
let evt = ... // create CancelableEvent;
this.myEvent$.emit(evt);
if(evt.canceled) return;  // check if it's canceled
...

// when subscribe event:
if(evt.canceled) throw 'event canceled by others';  // check if it's canceled
if(xxx) {
    evt.canceled = true;
    throw 'event canceled by me' // ignore following business logic
}
// business logic here
```

Comment: I did a slight improvement using native CustomEvent here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70386214/3317037